# SQL compound operations with null column values

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

In simple terms I need to evaluate a null column as a 0 in the case of compound operators.

I'm writing code for a pricing table, updating prices in a batch where the formulas for the update will need approval and are stored in a second table.

These formulas are user entered. The allowed inputs are empty string, any number, =(column based formula) and the compound operators like +=number. Empty strings will converted to null and stored in the table, in our case there is a base pricing row, and it coalesces the null in a specific row with the base row.

My issue is when the value was null, and a user inputs a compound operation say +=5 I end up with the column still being left null. Is there any simpler way to handle nulls in the table in compound operations other than converting `+=5` to `=COALESCE(column,0)+5` particularly considering that null values are acceptable in the table after the updates.

```
commandText.AppendLine($"SELECT IIF(pc.{columnName}='',NULL,pc.{columnName}), WhereClauseContent)");
commandText.AppendLine($"FROM {schema}.PriceChange pc");
```

Join...

Using a cursor into `@{columName}, @whereClause`

```
commandText.AppendLine("SELECT @Sql = 'UPDATE pr SET");
commandText.AppendLine($"pr.{columnName}'+IIF(ISNUMERIC(@{columnName})=1 OR @{columnName} IS NULL,'=','')+@{columnName}");
commandText.AppendLine($"FROM {schema}.Pricing pr");
```

Join...
    commandText.AppendLine("EXEC(@SQL)");

Comment: The aggregate `SUM` ignores `NULL` values (as do most aggregates). Other than that, I don't know what you're after.

Comment: @Andrew . . . You have the solution.  `= COALESCE(column,0) + 5` is considered pretty simple in the SQL world.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Note that the formula is user entered and stored in a table pending approvals, I don't want to modify the formula if there is any other way to handle it. I'm  after a way to null handle without having to pick apart stored SQL that is being executed dynamically

Comment: If your solution involves executing arbitrary stored SQL, you've got a bad solution (and a security nightmare). Having to "pick it apart" may not be such a bad thing. Either that or pass the buck to the people who insist on entering arbitrary SQL: educate them on the miracles of `COALESCE` (or `ISNULL` if you want it shorter). If you must parse the input, you don't want to do that in SQL anyway, because it's a bad language to do string manipulation in. Fortunately you've got a C# component.

Comment: @JeroenMostert That's where my issue is, SQL is bad for string manipulation, I am handling the security issues when I store it, rejecting anything with a ; validating everything against a whitelist of allowed functions, operations and table aliases, but I don't want to actually manipulate the function there if I can avoid it, and end up storing something other than entered. That's why I am looking for another answer, though I know one may not exist.

Comment: If you're already validating everything, I'm not sure what the problem is. Either wrap the outermost function application an `ISNULL(expr, 0)` to handle null coalescing for you if it's always desirable (and strip this transparently if the users aren't supposed to manipulate it), or allow manual applications of `ISNULL(...)` inside your formulas (since it's safe).

Comment: @JeroenMostert The issue is only with the compound operators, the `+=`, `-=`, `*=`, and `/=` Everything else will work, just those four operands... None of which can be wrapped in an ISNULL without converting them into `=self+value`

Comment: As SQL does not have compound operators with built-in `NULL` coalescing, I'm afraid you'll just have to bite the bullet and rewrite those operators specially. Actually, I'm surprised you didn't run into this limitation sooner, because most interesting formulas will have to explicitly refer to the column name one way or another. The compound operators are useful shorthand, but they're just that -- shorthand. They don't allow anything essentially new.

Comment: To make your own life simpler, consider disallowing the compound operators, but allowing the user to refer to "the current column" with a special syntax (like a solitary `@`).  This way formulas can still be reused easily and it's easier for you to stick in `NULL` coalescing (either fully automatically or by allowing something like `@!` to be shorthand for `ISNULL(column, 0)`).

Comment: @JeroenMostert It's the first time I've been asked to let the user write SQL directly into a text box, and wasn't able to convince the powers that be to do it another way.

Answer (score -1):

You have the solution, as I mention in a comment.

However, perhaps you don't want `NULL` values at all.  That could be an easy thing to arrange:

```
create table x (
    . . .
    col int not null default 0,
    . . .
)
```

Then, the column value will be zero instead of empty.  You seem to want zero values in that case, so this might be a solution to your problem.

Comment: I do want to allow null values, as I said in the question "in our case there is a base pricing row, and it coalesces the null in a specific row with the base row." As for using `coalesce`, sure that's simple enough, if the sql wan't being executed dynamically from sql stored in a table when the price changes are approved.